# Can ANTLR4 parser generator generate C code?

Tags: c, antlr, antlr4

I'm studying antlr4 and, in the documentation, I read that the main targets of this parser generator are: Java, C#, Python2|3, JavaScript, Go, C++, Swift. Instead, the previous version (antlr3) includes also C.

My question is: is there a way to generate C code also in antlr4? 
Thank you

Comment: The answer of Bart Kiers tells, that there is no C target. However, it is quite easy to make a C header file which declares functions, which are defined in a C++ code as `extern "C"` (and since it's C++ code, it can call the antlr4-genrated C++ code). Would such a wrapper serve your purpose?

Comment: Thank you, maybe this could be an option

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no, there is no C target.

You forgot one, btw: there's also a PHP target. At the time of this writing, these are the available targets:

- Java
- C#
- Python 2
- Python 3
- JavaScript
- Go
- C++
- Swift
- PHP

-- https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/targets.md

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm searching for a parser generator that generates top-down parser in C, Java, Python, and possibly JavaScript (but not required). Antlr4 could be an option because is very much used but, for my university course, C is a strong requirement.

Can you suggest to me other parsers generator with these features? 
What do you think about Coco/R?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with (LL) parser generators with a C target :(

Answer (score 1):

ANTLR4 parsing and code generation have been designed based-on object-oriented features such as inheritance and polymorphism, and so generating C target is a bit challenging because it not support object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a parser builder in Kotlin common code.
Native code is an option as a kotlin target, so the parser should callable from C code. Though I have not tested this very extensively.

It is not ANTLR4, the parsers generated by ANTLR are much faster.
But the syntax for defining a grammar is similar to ANTLR, so if you still need something, feel free to give it a try, and let me know how you get on.

Details can be found here:
https://medium.com/@dr.david.h.akehurst/a-kotlin-multi-platform-parser-usable-from-a-jvm-or-javascript-59e870832a79